# I'm searching for better way to seed cucumber tests with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, seeding

At the moment I have a quite big series of rake tasks that fill various system components with data. The problemis that I would like to reuse that code and data for cucumber tests. I found how to invoke rake tasks in cucumber step definitions and created a step seed_the_data. First scenario works fine, the problems start. For some reason some rake tasks refuse to run again. Digging in rake code I saw line

```
return if @already_run
```

I presume that using rake tasks is a bad idea. So I am looking for a good way to reuse my rake task data and code and use it in seeding cucumber tests. I want to avoid situation where my tests test data that is no longer used in production and the application fails spectacularly because tests were not testing seeding data used by production code.

### update 1

I ended up writing a module and called it SeedingHelper.It appears to do what I wanted. Now my rake tasks and test seeding uses the same code.

### update 2

Each scenario will start with blank state. My helper will let me to fill in the database with data required for the test. I hope it will be easier than with previous approach.

I consider the question closed, unless somebody comes up with better way of generating the jungle, so that I can test passing banana to the gorilla.

Comment: That's tough. I can't exactly visualize it. Can you provide more code, such as your env.rb and hooks.rb? Maybe even the rakefile contents (or key parts of it)?

Comment: The most common solution is to use fixtures or factories together with something like `database_cleaner` to clean out the database between test runs. It may be tempting to run specs on something like a copy of the real production database but that has a lot of potential problems since the data might be changing (your tests become non-deterministic) and you will encounter test ordering issues unless you reset the database state between each run. Doing that with a huge seedfile will slow your tests to a crawl.

Comment: @max - I have to groups several types of tasks: initial clean-up and set-up, default system configuration, default system data, company set-up and depot set-up. During company and depot set-up I need to copy some data from the default system configuration. I ran into a problem at this point. Because rake task did not create default system configuration while running the second scenario. I need a way to organise the test part of the system so it shares some data and code with the seeding system. We need to have a way of verifying if code changes break something or not.

Comment: Thats the whole point of tests - but you're missing my main point. You can use seed files to load the necessary system configuration but for the rest of the data you will want to use fixtures and factories and reset the slate totally between tests. Each test should have just enough of your buisness logic objects to test the feature under test. You might think that having a massive DB to run the tests agains might give you better acuity but in truth it will mask bugs.

Comment: A common one is that A might not work if a B is not present in the DB. But you won't catch it unless you have a blank state.